# Do I have to do something special to make a file a resource file in QT C++?

Tags: c++, qt, resources

Basically I have an image I'm trying to use as a splash screen.  I set up the splash screen and even told it the location(":/Nuclear_Vortex_100_About.jpg") but when I run the program, all I see is a general window background "window"(no close box or any of the decoration, just a widget for lack of a better word) and no image on it.

I added the file (along with a bunch of other images I want to later load and use in the app) and they show up in the "Other Files" folder - ok so I figured since they're in the project, that they would be seen as resources if not source or headers.  Do I need to add a special section to the PRO file or something in order to use the file?  I'm about to just hard code an absolute path just to get it to work but I want a system independent way to get this done. I'm going to be paid for this project and I don't have much experience with the resource system in QT but it wasn't hard in Visual Studio and other C++ environments.  As I see the splash screen show up, I know that part is working.  The only thing I don't know for sure is that the file is not being found - that is I have not verified by using QFile and checking if it exists - I'll be doing that after I post this as it'll take some time to get a response or 2.

I **have** been searching for over a day and a half all over google and haven't found anything telling me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create resource file (.qrc) and add picture in it. It'll appear in resources section of your project. Then you can use it freely in your program.

Comment: That's all?  Just add a qrc file to the project folder and then use QT Creator to add it to the project and it'll be accessible?  Is there some link where I can find the syntax for the QRC ile?  I only know about the PRO file right now.  Thank you by the way.  When I have had a chance to try it out and it works, I'll upvote and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work sir - I still have the splash screen showing without an image.  I went to QT's reference for the resource system and it showed me an example of a QRC file.  I added one in QT Creator and it wanted some prefix attribute to that qresource tag.  I took it off as per the example.

Comment: I'm sorry that DID work - I'm an idiot lol - I had removed the ":/" from the filename path URI for the QPixMap in the Splash Screen subclass as when I put a QFile and used qDebug to detect if the file existed - it said it exists and then I noticed that problem - so I set your answer as accepted and upvoted it - Thank you muchly!!!